# return wrong parameter when I use mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to have dynamic url like this format :

```
[SITE_URL]/[MODULE]/[PARAMETERS]
```

so I wrote this `mod_rewrite` code :

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ module.php?mod=$1&req=$2 [L]
```

example url is :
test-domain.com/users/register/step/2

and above `mod_rewrite` code will return parameters to php but I have this parameters in my php :

```
echo $_GET['mod']; // return users/register/step/2
echo $_GET['req']; // return empty
```

I want my rewrite code return `users` as `mod` and `register/step/2` as `req` to `module.php` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ module.php?mod=$1&req=$2 [L]
```